# CRITICAL_ERROR 65535

Tags: vba, excel

I have a simple VBA routine I have used before but seem to keep returning Critical_Error 65535 ..this is my routine..it fails at the save part post generating the values only excel file ..any pointers please?

---

```
Sub SaveFile()
'Recalc Sheets prior to saving down

a = MsgBox("Do you want to Save down todays Consultant Performance Report ?", vbOKCancel)
If a = 2 Then Exit Sub

Dim SaveSheets As Variant
Dim strFilename As String
Dim sheetListRange As Range
Dim sheetName As Variant
Dim wksheet As Variant

Dim wkbSrc As Workbook
Dim wkbNew As Workbook
Dim wksNew As Worksheet
Dim wksSrc As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer

  On Error GoTo ErrorHandler


  strFilename = Worksheets("Control").Range("SavePath").Value & "DailyReport_" & Format$(Now(), "YYYYMMDD") & ".xls"


  Set sheetListRange = Worksheets("Control").Range("SaveList")
  Set wkbSrc = ActiveWorkbook
  Set wkbNew = Workbooks.Add
  i = 0

  For Each sheetName In sheetListRange
    If sheetName = "" Then GoTo NEXT_SHEET
    For Each wksheet In wkbSrc.Sheets
      If wksheet.Name = sheetName Then
        i = i + 1
        wksheet.Copy Before:=wkbNew.Sheets(i)
        Set wksNew = ActiveSheet
        With wksNew
          .Cells.Select
          .Cells.Copy
          .Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
          .Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        End With
        ActiveWindow.Zoom = 75
        GoTo NEXT_SHEET
      End If
    Next wksheet
NEXT_SHEET:
  Next sheetName

  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  'dont need the default new sheets created by created a new workbook
  wkbNew.Worksheets("Sheet1").Delete
  wkbNew.Worksheets("Sheet2").Delete
  wkbNew.Worksheets("Sheet3").Delete

  ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=strFilename, FileFormat:=xlWorkbookNormal
  ActiveWorkbook.Close
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
  Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:

    'If there is an unknown runtime error give the user the error number and associated description
    '(Description is already set if the erorr is G_LNG_CRITICAL_ERROR)
    If Err.Number <> CRITICAL_ERROR Then Err.Description = "Run-time error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description

    Err.Description = "Error saving worksheet as file: " & Err.Description

    'Raise the error up to the error handler above
    Err.Raise Number:=CRITICAL_ERROR

End Sub
```

Comment: What line does the error occur on?

Comment: Comment out `On Error GoTo ErrorHandler` - what happens?

Comment: breaks here  wkbNew.Worksheets("Sheet2").Delete

Comment: And what's the error message?

Comment: Do you have a "Sheet2"?  I have my settings set to only create one sheet in each new workbook - perhaps you do too.  If you are only creating one dummy sheet in each new workbook, why would you want to delete "Sheet2" which won't exist?

Comment: doh.... thanks very much ..I haven't used VBA in an age so much appreciated...no need to delete "Sheet2" cheers Andy